# Get div height in pixels although its height set to 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if there is any way to get div height in pixels, although its height set earlier to 100% height.
This is required as div content is dynamic so div height has different values based on content itself.

**[Edit]**
Div by default is hidden.

I need to get div height in pixels for later manipulation (smooth scrolling will be done for div)?
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? or you want a pure JS solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery, use

```
$("#myElement").height();
```

http://api.jquery.com/height/

For Plain Ol' Javascript, you can use [`element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight) or [`element.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight), depending on which one suits your needs.

---

Since the div is hidden, you will have to `.show()` it before calling `.height()`, and you can hide it again straight away:

```
var $myEl  = $('#myElement').show();
var height = $myEl.height();
$myEl.hide();
```

Comment: element.clientHeight or element.offsetHeight return "0", as div is hidden by default.

Comment: @Ahmed: hidden elements have no "pixel height", so you cannot get height in pixels without showing the element first, then hiding it again afterwards.  If you hide right after showing and getting the height value, the display will not be updated to show the element.

Answer (score 12):

```
theDiv.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

```
$("#divInQuestion").height();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function:

```
$('#divid').height()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well on slow browsers the show/hide method MIGHT cause the box to flicker (though the computer have to be really slow). So if you want to avoid this, give the div a opacity: 0 - and perhaps even a position: absolute, so it doesnt push the content. So to extend the code from before:

```
var $myEl  = $('#myElement').css({"opacity": "0", "position": "absolute"}).show();
var height = $myEl.height();
$myEl.hide().css({"opacity": "", "position": ""});
```

But again. This might be overkill.